# retrieve data or record from DB in JSON format Django

Tags: django, django-views

I have this model

```
class Pharmacy(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length = 256)
contact = models.CharField(max_length = 15)
city = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
address = models.TextField()
lat = models.FloatField()
long = models.FloatField()

def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

it is views.py

```
def PharmacyJsonList(request):
data = serializers.serialize('json',Pharmacy.objects.all())
return JsonResponse({'data':data})
```

result is in this format [image]

I want just fields in json format without these **slushes**
could I do it in Class Base View?

Comment: Those slushes are auto-added, because you are using quote signs in quotes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your view, after serializing the queryset, just return your response in HttpResponse with `content_type="application/json"`.

```py
from django.http import HttpResponse

def PharmacyJsonList(request):
    data = serializers.serialize('json',Pharmacy.objects.all())
    return HttpResponse(data, content_type='application/json'))
```

another way is to use `values()` with queryset and then send the response by `JsonResponse`

```py
from django.http import JsonResponse

def PharmacyJsonList(request):
    data = list(Pharmacy.objects.values())
    return JsonResponse({'data': data})
```

Comment: it generates the same result.

Comment: which one? first approach or second? or both?

Comment: both give the same results.

Comment: how are you checking the result?

Comment: thank you so much.it's working but could get just fields

Comment: I didn't get this "but could get just fields". can you explain?

Comment: it solved as you guide me, but now result is [{}] this form. how could I get the output without [] these brackets?

Comment: thats list of items, in your image the data is in same format, {"data": [{}]}

Comment: `def PharmacyJsonList(request):
    data = list(Pharmacy.objects.values())
    return JsonResponse(data, safe = False)` I return in this form. but it generate [{}] in this formate. I need json just in this {} formate.

Comment: hi, i wonder can we replace the key ? example {"oldkey" : "value"} into {"newkey" : "value"}

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
return JsonResponse({'data': Pharmacy.objects.all()})
```

Comment: Same results as before.

Comment: have another way which retrieve data from DB in JSON format?

Answer (score 0):

After serializing the queryset, we can also load the json into a dictionary before sending it as JsonResponse. This should also give your desired output without slashes.

```
from django.core.serializers import serialize
import json

def PharmacyJsonList(request):
  data = serializers.serialize('json',Pharmacy.objects.all())
  data = json.loads(data)
  return JsonResponse(data, safe=False, status=200)
```